# Can't get higher order function find to work

Tags: javascript, find, higher-order-functions

I'm a fairly new webdev student, I am currently working on an exercise we got but I'm stuck. I have an array with objects and the goal is to manipulate them using higher-order functions.

```
let bookList = [
    {
    title:"The Way of Kings",
    author: "B Sanderson",
    pages: 900,
    isAvailable:false
    },
    {
    title:"Words of radiance",
    author: "B Sanderson",
    pages: 1087,
    isAvailable:true
    },  
    {
    title:"Oathbringer",
    author: "B Sanderson",
    pages: 1000,
    isAvailable:false
    }
];
```

I am given some code as a starting point that I am not allowed to change. I am supposed to write a function that returns true if an exact title exists in my bookList.

```
function hasBook(title, bookShelf) {
}
```

This is what I have so far, and I have no clue how to progress further. here I get an error saying that bookList is not a function, but I can't figure out how to make this work. I understand that I've messed something up and that I probably don't fully understand how to use find with the default code is given.

```
function hasBook(title, bookShelf) {
    if (title === bookShelf.titel) {
         return true;
    }
}

bookList.find(hasBook("Oathbringer", bookList ));
```

Hopefully, you understand what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `some` method - 
The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```js
let bookList = [
    {
    title:"The Way of Kings",
    author: "B Sanderson",
    pages: 900,
    isAvailable:false
    },
    {
    title:"Words of radiance",
    author: "B Sanderson",
    pages: 1087,
    isAvailable:true
    },

    {
    title:"Oathbringer",
    author: "B Sanderson",
    pages: 1000,
    isAvailable:false
    }
];


function hasBook(title, bookShelf) {

 return bookShelf.some((o) => o.title.toLowerCase() === title.toLowerCase());
}

console.log(hasBook('Oathbringer', bookList));
```

Comment: Oh, i didnt know that `some()` returned a bool, that seems to be what i want.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
function hasBook(title, bookShelf) {
    const book = bookShelf.find(book => book.title === title)
    return book ? true : false;
}
```

Then, you call it like this:

```
const result = hasBook("Oathbringer", bookList)
```

Follows a full working example:

```js
let bookList = [
    {
    title:"The Way of Kings",
    author: "B Sanderson",
    pages: 900,
    isAvailable:false
    },
    {
    title:"Words of radiance",
    author: "B Sanderson",
    pages: 1087,
    isAvailable:true
    },

    {
    title:"Oathbringer",
    author: "B Sanderson",
    pages: 1000,
    isAvailable:false
    }
];


function hasBook(title, bookShelf) {
    const book = bookShelf.find(book => book.title === title)
    return book ? true : false;
}



console.log(`Has book ${hasBook("Oathbringer", bookList)}`);
```